# node.jsでcannot find module というエラーの対処法

Tags: node.js

よろしくお願いいたします。

google-home-notifierがあるフォルダにおいて
https://qiita.com/kyota/items/453047f236ca5488027c
を参考に、最初のmain.jsを実行しようとしたのですが、

Error: Cannot find module 'google-home-notifier'

というエラーが出てしまいました。
このようにgooge-home-notifier.jsがあるフォルダと同じフォルダ内に実行したい
ファイルがある場合のエラーに対する解決方法を教えていただければ幸いです。

Answer (score 1):

google-home-notifierのインストール方法を間違えていらっしゃると思います。google-home-notifier.jsをダウンロードしてくるのではなく、記事にあるように`npm`を使ってインストールする必要があります。

`main.js`があるフォルダ内で次のコマンドを実行することにより、`npm`を用いてgoogle-home-notifierをインストールしてください。（記事のコマンドはちょっとミスがあるようですので、以下に正しいコマンドを示します。）

```
$ npm init
$ npm i google-home-notifier
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。エラーが消えました。npmを使うのとダウンロードしてくるのではどう違うのでしょうか。

Comment: まず最初に、node.js用のモジュールを、npmを使わずにダウンロードしてくるというのはほとんどありえません。常にnpmを使いましょう。　　npmを使うことにより、`require('google-home-notifier')`のようにrequireでモジュール名を指定するだけでモジュールを使用できて便利です。もし自分でダウンロードしてきた場合は`require('./google-home-notifier./s')`のようにファイルへの相対パスを指定します。　　常にnpmを使うべき理由ですが、今回使用したモジュールであるgoogle-home-notifierは、さらにいくつもの別のモジュールを使用しています。なので、google-home-notifier.jsだけをダウンロードするのではなく使われているモジュールも全部ダウンロードしてくる必要があります。そのダウンロードしてきたモジュールがさらに別のモジュールを使っていて……みたいな事態もありえますから、これを人の手でやるのは現実的ではありません。このような作業を自動でやってくれるのがnpmなのです（一般に、こういうのをパッケージマネージャと言います）。

Comment: 詳しい説明をしていただきありがとうございます。理解できました。